# Should I anticipate complications as US Citizen flying to Paris from Canada?

Tags: air-travel, france, canada, international-travel, us-citizens

I'm a US citizen traveling to Paris in a week via a drive across the border from Michigan to Windsor, Canada, a flight from Windsor to Toronto, and finally a flight from Toronto to Paris.

Should I anticipate any border crossing difficulties coming to or from Canada? What about customs at the airport?

I chose to fly from Windsor instead of Detroit because it was several hundred dollars cheaper, and am hoping I didn't invite a lot of complications.

Comment: In a word: no.  Why would you?

Comment: This is a normal activity. Unless you are transporting weird goods, I don't see why anyone would be interested.

Comment: Canadians often do the same, crossing the border south to catch a cheaper flight, never heard of any issues doing so.

Comment: Certainly not. Just don't cut it too close on time.

Answer (score 4):

It's already been explained in several comments but since it seems no other answer is forthcoming, I will repeat it here: There is no reason to expect any difficulties.

Plan some time to cross the border and don't take anything that might create issues with customs like weapons, drugs, large quantities of alcohol, etc. (but those could be equally problematic when landing in Europe or flying back…) and you should be fine.

Comment: this, maybe americans are not used to this but in certain areas it's very normal to cross borders to reach a major airport.